# Count rows or store value MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to see how many different users have connected to a website but not sure if I should count the rows in the users database or store a separate value that is incremented each time a user registers.

What are the benefits to using a value as opposed to counting rows in speed, reliability etc.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to count the number of users, not the logins per user, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: connected or registered?

Comment: Registered, for example the number of users on SO.

Comment: @user2248702 . . . How often do you need to know the number of users compared to the frequency that users connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table is not huge (you dont have many users) you should use count.

If you have a huge table, you better use another table to store the count of users, or if an approximate row count is sufficient, you can also use `SHOW TABLE STATUS` ([ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-table-status.html))

You have some util information here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html

> InnoDB does not keep an internal count of rows in a table because concurrent transactions might “see” different numbers of rows at the same time. To process a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t statement, InnoDB scans an index of the table, which takes some time if the index is not entirely in the buffer pool. If your table does not change often, using the MySQL query cache is a good solution. To get a fast count, you have to use a counter table you create yourself and let your application update it according to the inserts and deletes it does.[...] See [Section 14.3.14.1, “InnoDB Performance Tuning Tips”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-tuning.html).

I hope @GordonLinoff or some other sql guru can give you more information about when a table is considered big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of them.

I would just update the timestamp for the user each time he clicks something.

Then you could just fetch all this timestamps and could check the time of the last activity.

If you would just increment a value then you have the problem that you do not know if the user has been disconnected already.

With this approach you have a perfect overview over a user´s last activity.

That's the way how it is handled in most of the software for example forums.

It works bor both guests (normal visitors) and registered users if you log the client´s ip.

Comment: I deleted the post, i posted before seeing your post. Sorry